# Machine Learning - Train a model using imbalanced data

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, xgboost, lightgbm

I have two classes in my data.

This is how class distribution looks like.

```
0.0    169072
1.0     84944
```

In other words, I have 2:1 class distribution.

I believe I have two choices. Downsample the class `0.0` or upsample class `1.0`. If I go with option 1, I'm losing data. If i go with option 2, then I'm using non-real data.

Is there a way, I can train the model without upsample or downsample?

This is how my classification_report looks like.

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.68      1.00      0.81     51683
         1.0       1.00      0.00      0.00     24522

    accuracy                           0.68     76205
   macro avg       0.84      0.50      0.40     76205
weighted avg       0.78      0.68      0.55     76205
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend either approach.

I'm thinking about models to detect fraud.  By definition, fraud should be a small percentage of outcomes - on the order of 1-5%.  Changing the percentage for training would be a gross distortion of the problem being solved.

Better to leave the proportions as they are.

Make sure that your train, validation, and test data sets all have ratios that reflect the real problem.

Adjust your outcome instead.  Don't go for accuracy.  A naive model that assumes the 0 outcome will be correct 2/3rds of the time.  You want your model to be better than that or a weighted coin flip.

I'd recommend using [recall](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tour-of-evaluation-metrics-for-imbalanced-classification/) as your criterion for success.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I have updated my question with classification_report. Could you tell me why my model is biased towards class 0?  As you can see, the recall value for class `1.0` is `0.0`. So no data is picked from that category.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can answer.  I see from the tags that you used XGBoost, which is a very good choice.  Something else is clearly wrong.  Perhaps you can try a tabular logistic regression and see how that does.  Swap out the model and compare.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is slightly imbalanced yes, but it does not mean that you only have one of the two options (under or over sample your data). You can leave the data as is and apply cost sensitive training in your model. For example, if in your case the classes have a match of `2:1`, then you need to give a *weight* of `2` to your minority class. In the example of an XGBoost classifier, this argument is called `scale_pos_weight`. See more in this excellent [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/xgboost-for-imbalanced-classification/).

Regarding model evaluation, you should use a classification report to have a full intuition of your model's true and false predictions (precision and recall are your two best friends in this process!).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just updated the question with classification_report.

Comment: It seems that your model is predicting only 0 all the time. If you are using XGBoost, remember to keep the data as it is : so no normalization, just a encode categorical variables into numbers, no one hot encoding (since it is consistently worse than juste encoding) and add the weight parameter. Also, make sure the test set has the same order of features!

Comment: If you checked all those points and you still get a poor performance (no skill model that predicts only 0) then it might be a good idea to take a step back and explore your features (i.e. data distributions, missing values) see if you can spot any visible patterns with respect to your two classes. @John

Comment: Noted with thanks.